# Сделать подобный 5 0 4 1 3 2 2 3 1 4 0 5 вывод в цикле for

Tags: php, циклы

мне нужно несколько примеров вывода значений 5 0 4 1 3 2 2 3 1 4 0 5 через цикл FOR (PHP) Код нужен не замудреный а самый простой для новичка.

Я пытаюсь вывести так, но что то не то.

```
function t5()////////////
{
    global $out5;
    $x = "";
    $z = 0;

    for ($i = 5; $i >= $z; $i--){
        $x .= $i." ";// 5 4 3 2 1 0
        if ($i > $z){
            $x = "";
            $x = $i; 
            $i = $z;
            $z = $x; 
        }
        $x .= $i + 1 ." ";// 0 1 2 3 4 5
    }
        $out5 = $x;
    echo $out5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никаких сравнений и прочих сложностей не надо.
Нечетные элементы равны `$i`, четные `5-$i`. Просто в цикле

```
$x .= $i." ".5-$i." ";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ошибка выходила. Подправил так $x .= 5 - $i." "; все заработало. еще раз спасибо.